# Using variable in multiple frames

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, global-variables, frames

Currently trying to create a website on a static server. Out of JSON-code it should create the navigation in one frame and in a right sideframe a "previous" and "next" button according to the current position in the hierarchy.

I think the problem is that my "global variables" chap and subchap (which you are gonna find in the code below) cannot be accessed over all the 3 frames. I didn't know a way to simplify the problem, I'm sorry for the large post.

I got all the files on my server if you want to see it live: http://fabitosh.bplaced.net/SkriptET/start.html
Files: http://fabitosh.bplaced.net/SkriptET/
files.json isn't used in the code but clearer to look at than the implementation in json.js

At first the basic structure:

index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="json.js"></script>
<!--     <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> -->
  </head>
    <frameset cols="300,*,300">
    <frame src="navigation.html" name="navigation"/>
    <frame src="elladq.html" name="content"/>
    <frame src="sidebar.html" name="rightsidebar"/>
    </frameset>
</html>
```

navigation.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="json.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
    <base target="content">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="left">
        Die Navigation<br/>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

rightsidebar.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="json.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="right">
        Die Sidebar <br/>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            alert("I reloaded!");
        </script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now it's getting a bit complicated. The following parts are out of javascript.js. I'm gonna try to explain my thoughts behind the different parts.

The variables chap and subchap are thought as kind of a memory of the current position in the hierarchy. Depending on what link you click on they should adapt. The navigation-frame should never reload, so I hope they can kinda be saved there. (Big question mark)

```
$(document).ready(function(){ // DOM needs to exist in order to be able to add stuff in there
    //JSON-Data coming out of json.js which also converts it in a way to be accessed by data.chapter[chap].subchapter[subchap]
    var chap = 1; //position in the array of the currently open chapter
    var subchap = 0; //position in the array of the currently open subchapter
```

The following part kinda works. The navigation is created according to the JSON-structure. When pressing on a link, the right frame reloads (at least on the ftp-Server, it doesn't locally).
When clicking on a link the variables chap and subchap should take the values of the element number in the array. (-> onclick='..')

```
        //********* Create Navigation out of JSON File *********
        for(var i = 0; i < data.chapter.length; i++) { 
            $('#left').append("<a href='"+data.chapter[i].url+"' target='content'>"+data.chapter[i].title+"</a></b><ul>");
            for(var j = 0; j < data.chapter[i].subchapter.length; j++) {
                $('#left').append("<li><a href='"+data.chapter[i].subchapter[j].url+"' onclick='chap="+i+"; subchap="+j+"; parent.rightsidebar.location.reload();'>"+data.chapter[i].subchapter[j].title+"</a></li>"); // target="content"; defined in sidebar.html header
            }
            $('#left').append("</ul>");
        }
```

This is what yet isn't working. The variables chap and subchap do not have the values which I want them to have. 
When clicking on the "Next:" link, the subchap should increase by one.

```
        //********* Previous Page / Next Page *********
        if (subchap>0){
            $('#right').append("<a href='"+data.chapter[chap].subchapter[subchap-1].url+"' target='content' onclick='subchap-=1; parent.rightsidebar.location.reload();'> Previous: "+data.chapter[chap].subchapter[subchap-1].title+"</a><br/>");
        } if (subchap<data.chapter[chap].subchapter.length) {
            $('#right').append("<a href='>"+data.chapter[chap].subchapter[subchap+1].url+"' target='content' onclick='subchap+=1; parent.rightsidebar.location.reload();'> Next: "+data.chapter[chap].subchapter[subchap+1].title+"</a><br/>");
        }
});
```

Comment: [Please, please don't use HTML frames.](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/why-frames-suck-most-of-the-time/) It's an outdated technology which is better served by using `display:fixed` to lock your navigation in place, and AJAX to retrieve sections of a page without redirecting.

Comment: @Blazemonger: I think I am aware of this. Problem is that it should be possible to run the page on a memory stick / any computer. That's why I avoid AJAX. As the page doesn't need to be found by search engines, neither be bookmarked, I decided to go for frames. Back then I had the impression it should be possible to kind of save a variable with the current position using frames and a non-reloading navigation frame. If the whole page is reloading I wouldn't know a way to do so.

Answer (score 0):

In an iframe you can access `window.parent`

So...

in your main window:

`window.cake = "Tasty!"`

then in your iframe:

`var isTasty = window.parent.cake`

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason your chap and subchap variables are not incrementing or decrementing is because of the way you assigned the onclick events. By inlining the javascript like that, you have to have subchap and chap declared at the global level. 
Move

```
var chap = 1;
var subchap = 0;
```

to the line before

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

so it will look like the following:

```
var chap = 1;
var subchap = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){
   //ready code here
});
```

You may also want to consider using the jquery .on("click", function(){}).

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.chapter.length; i++) { 
    $('#left').append("<a href='"+data.chapter[i].url+"' target='content'>"+data.chapter[i].title+"</a></b>");
    var subChapUl = $('<ul class="subchap-list"></ul>');
    for(var j = 0; j < data.chapter[i].subchapter.length; j++) {
        var subChap = $('<li><a href="'+data.chapter[i].subchapter[j].url+'" data-subchap="' + j + '" data-chap="' + i + '">'+data.chapter[i].subchapter[j].title+'</a></li>');
        subChap.on("click",subChapClick);
        subChapUl.append(subChap);
    }
        $('#left').append(subChapUl);
}    

//at the global level define the following function:
function subChapClick(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var el = $(e.target);
     chap = el.attr("data-chap");
     subchap = el.attr("data-subchap");
     parent.rightsidebar.location.reload();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I've adapted my code accordingly. Whilst the page sets up perfectly, sadly the global variables still don't change. An other thing I noticed is that e.preventDefault() makes the links go bad, meaning the content-frame doesn't change anymore. I decided to comment it out, the updated files are online in case you are curious.